# How to change values of a JSON object in an app from a module?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, module, object-literal

I have a JS app file with a JSON object.

What I want to do is take this object, send it to a module file, change the values, and send it back to change the values of the JSON object in the app file. If that makes sense.

How do I do this?

This is the JSON object in the app file:

```
NRXA.reactorOne = {
    powerOn: true,
    temperature: 10,
    pressure: 10,
    coolant: 10,
    systemFailure: false,
    performance: 10,
    powerOutput: 10
};
```

This is currently the function in the module file where I'm trying to change the values:

```
function setPowerOffStandardValues(reactor){
    let newReactor = reactor;

    newReactor = {
        powerOn: false,
        temperature: 0,
        pressure: 0,
        coolant: 0,
        systemFailure: false,
        performance: 0,
        powerOutput: 0
    };

    return newReactor;

}
```

And this is how I'm calling the module function in the app:

```
NRXA.reactorOne = NuclearReactorXModule.setPowerOffStandardValues(NRXA.reactorOne);
```

My error message is that the setPowerOffStandardValues function is undefined and I'm lost at what to change because I'm a complete noob at this, also I'm tired and stressed because of exams so there might be obvious mistakes I'm not able to see lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure to `export` the `setPowerOffStandardValues` function in its module. Change it to

`export function setPowerOffStandardValues(reactor){`

so that other modules can reference it.